# Undefined index: imagedescription[n] (array problem)

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm trying to get the value of an array but I can't.
I've got this page to upload a variable number of photos and their relative descriptions (to be stored in a DB)

```
for ($i=1; $i<$val; $i++)
{
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-2">';
    echo '<div class="file-field"  style="margin-bottom: 10px;">';
    echo '<div class="z-depth-1-half mt-3" id="thumb-output'.$i.'"></div>';
    echo '<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">';
    echo '<div class="custom-file">';
    echo '<input type="file" data-index="'.$i.'" name="imageupload[]" class="custom-file-input"  aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon'.$i.'">';
    echo '<label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile'.$i.'">IMG '.$i.'</label>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-6 mt-4">';
    echo '<label for="imagedescription'.$i.'">Description IMG '.$i.'</label>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="imagedescription[]" class="form-control mt-2" id="imagedescription'.$i.'" aria-describedby="ImageDescription'.$i.'" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="imgcount" value="'.$i.'">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

and this page that "take" and process the datas.

```
 for($i = 0; $i < $count_tmp_name_array; $i++){
    $extension = pathinfo($name_array[$i] , PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $j=$i+1;
    $imgname = $albumtitle."-".$j.".".$extension;
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], $target_dir.$imgname)){
        $photo_decription = $_POST['imagedescription['.$i.']'];
        print_r ($photo_decription);
        echo "</br>";
}
```

Basically what I need to do is to assign the varous values of the array imagedescription[] to the relative image (to be upoaded to the DB).
Something like:

```
[...]
imagedescription[1] -> imageupload[1];
imagedescription[2] -> imageupload[2];
imagedescription[3] -> imageupload[3];
[etc]
```

The rest is working good but when I try to print the value of **$photo_decription** or **$_POST['imagedescription['.$i.']']** (either with echo or print_r, it doesn't make difference) I recieve the error `"Undefined Index for imagedescription[1]", "Undefined Index for imagedescription[2]", "Undefined Index for imagedescription[3]", etc.`

[image]

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: You are trying to access `$_POST['imagedescription[0]']` here, but the key is just `imagedescription`, and that entry itself is an array. You want `$_POST['imagedescription'][0]`.

Comment: It was that easy?! I spent all day trying to figure out :/
Thank You so much man